# Stepping down as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

I have decided to step down as pro-tem moderator of Signal Processing Stack Exchange and have informed the SE team of my decision (I will stay on until the new pro-tems are picked).

When the [moderator pro-temprore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) program was established, Stack Exchange had a strict "graduate in 90 days or you're bust" policy, which meant that pro-tem mods served at the most for perhaps 4-5 months before the official elections. However, as more and more sites were added and the topics started getting diverse and further and further away from a typical programmer's hobbies & interests, sites started staying longer in beta (in 3 more months, [Personal Finance & Money](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) will have been in beta for 1000 days!).

The role of a pro-temp moderator on a beta site is, in some ways, more challenging than on established and graduated sites. One has to delicately guide the community in editing/curating content, closing/deleting spam and off-topic content, teach new users the ways and mores of the site (and Stack Exchange), initiate/steer ideas and discussions on meta and generally be current with the pulse of the site. However, the challenges facing a beta site (or any site, for that matter) also evolve with time and it is easy for veteran users/original pro-tems to get blindsided by these new challenges.

Unfortunately, I don't find the time to be active here as I used to be, and this also places additional workload on the other two mods, which is unfair. We still have a long ways to go before we graduate and hopefully, the new pro-tem picks will have the time and patience to guide the community and see us through graduation.

Thank you all for the opportunity!

Comment: Thanks for being around. You've been a great mentor to me when we were just starting out. Hope you'll still visit the site occasionally.

Comment: Cheers @yoda. I don't think the site could have gotten off the ground as well as it did without your expertise. Thanks again for all the effort you've put in here--I know we'll all feel a disturbance in the force when you step down.

Comment: @yoda: Thanks for all of the work.